# How to get random image from directory using PHP

Tags: php

I have one directory called images/tips.

Now in that directory I have many images which can change.

I want the PHP script to read the directory, to find the images, and out of those images found to pick a random image.

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
$imagesDir = 'images/tips/';

$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

$randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)]; // See comments
```

You can send a 2nd argument to `array_rand()` to get more than 1.

Comment: Actually, you'd have to do
$randomImage=$images[array_rand($images)];

From the manual:
"array_rand() returns the key for a random entry."

Comment: thank buddy , that worked perfectly
This webiste is great for getting help.

Is there any option that when some comment is posted or answers is given i get email  because i had three answers and i didn't get email , i ticked the notify box but still could not get email

Answer (score 4):

```
$images = glob('images/tips/*');
return $images[rand(0, count($images) - 1)];
```

However, this doesn't ensure that the same image isn't picked twice consecutively.

Comment: Adding that insurance would detract from the randomness.  It also might introduce bugs.

Comment: I had no clue that glob() function existed.  Nice.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
   foreach (glob("gallery/*") as $filename) {
         echo '<li><a href="'.$filename.'" title=""><img src="'.$filename.'" alt="" /></a> </li>';      
       }
?>
```

Look at this code, use it definitely if useful for you.  It loads all files from folder and prints them in above format. I made this code to use with lightbox.

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_rand_img($dir)
{
    $arr = array();
    $list = scandir($dir);
    foreach($list as $file)
    {
        if(!isset($img))
        {
            $img = '';
        }
        if(is_file($dir . '/' . $file))
        {
            $ext = end(explode('.', $file));
            if($ext == 'gif' || $ext == 'jpeg' || $ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'png' || $ext == 'GIF' || $ext == 'JPEG' || $ext == 'JPG' || $ext == 'PNG')
            {
                array_push($arr, $file);
                $img = $file;
            }
        }
    }
    if($img != '')
    {
        $img = array_rand($arr);
        $img = $arr[$img];
    }
    $img = str_replace("'", "\'", $img);
    $img = str_replace(" ", "%20", $img);
    return $img;
}


echo get_rand_img('images');
```

replace 'images' with your folder.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with alexa.
Use simple function.

```
function RandImg($dir)
{
$images = glob($dir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

$randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];
return $randomImage;
}

$the_image = RandImg('images/tips/');
echo $the_image;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$folder = "images";
$results_img_arr = array();
if (is_dir($folder))
{
        if ($handle = opendir($folder))
        {
                while(($file = readdir($handle)) !== FALSE)
                {
                    if(!in_array($file,array(".","..")))
                        $results_img_arr[] = $folder."/".$file;
               }
         closedir($handle);
        }
}
$ran_img_key  = array_rand($results_img_arr);

$img_path = $results_img_arr[$ran_img_key];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [opendir()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) to read in the filenames from that directory, storing each filename in an array.  Then use [rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) with a min and max corresponding to your array keys to select an item from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler:

```
$directory = "medias/photos/";
$img = glob($directory . "*.jpg");
shuffle($img);
```

Comment: Problem is, this would only find `jpg` images, and it does a lot of unnecessary work by shuffling the whole array (may or may not be a problem, depending on how many images you have in the folder).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple php script for my personal use. Now I want share it with stackoverflow's community. Usage is simple: create a folder `"php"` into root of your Web Server and put inside this file php `rotate.php`... now create two folders into your root called `"pic"` and `"xmas"`... you can adjust the folder names by editing the var `$my_folder_holiday` and `$my_folder_default`...

```
<?php
  ##########################################################
  # Simple Script Random Images Rotator • 1.4 • 04.01.2020 #
  # Alessandro Marinuzzi [alecos] • https://www.alecos.it/ #
  ##########################################################
  function rotate($folder) {
    if ((file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/$folder")) && (is_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/$folder"))) {
      $list = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/$folder");
      $fileList = array();
      $img = '';
      foreach ($list as $file) {
        if ((file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']  . "/$folder/$file")) && (is_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']  . "/$folder/$file"))) {
          $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
          if ($ext == 'gif' || $ext == 'jpeg' || $ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'png') {
            $fileList[] = $file;
          }
        }
      }
      if (count($fileList) > 0) {
        $imageNumber = time() % count($fileList);
        $img = $folder . '/' . $fileList[$imageNumber];
      }
      return $img;
    } else {
      mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/$folder", 0755, true);
    }
  }
  $my_gallery_month = date('m');
  $my_folder_default = 'pic';
  $my_folder_holiday = 'xmas';
  if ($my_gallery_month == 12) {
    $my_gallery = rotate($my_folder_holiday);
  } else {
    $my_gallery = rotate($my_folder_default);
  }
?>
```

This script was tested under PHP 7.0/7.1/7.2/7.3 and PHP 7.4 and works fine. Usage (for example in root you may have a folder `"pic"` and `"xmas"` containing your images):

```
<a href="/<?php include("php/rotate.php"); echo $my_gallery; ?>"><img src="/<?php echo $my_gallery; ?>" alt="Random Gallery" width="90" height="67"></a>
```

Other usage using `FancyBox` library:

```
<a href="/<?php include("php/rotate.php"); echo $my_gallery; ?>" data-fancybox><img src="/<?php echo $my_gallery; ?>" alt="Random Gallery" width="90" height="67"></a>
```

Hope this Helps.

Answer (score -1):

Load folder with images:

```
$folder = opendir(images/tips/);
```

Build table out of files/images from directory:

```
$i = 0;
while(false !=($file = readdir($folder))){
if($file != "." && $file != ".."){
    $images[$i]= $file;
    $i++;
    }
}
```

Pick random:

```
$random_img=rand(0,count($images)-1);
```

Show on page:

```
echo '<img src="images/tips'.$images[$random_img].'" alt="" />';
```

Comment: Two issues. Don't you need another slash after `tips`?
And why not just do `$images[] = $file` and forget the counter?