# how to get images from a directory using glob - previous post not working

Tags: php

I'm new to php and I'm trying to get a directory listing of images.
I saw this post: [How to get random image from directory using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761252/how-to-get-random-image-from-directory-using-php)

I am trying to do nearly the same thing- choosing a random image and drawing it to the page via an  tag.

For some reason, the specification to the directory that I am using doesn't work, but I'm not sure why.  I've tried the following:

```
$localdir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp_content/themes/overlandconsulting_2010/images/headers/*.{jpg,gif,png}';
$images = glob($localdir, GLOB_BRACE);

$httpdir = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/wp_content/themes/overlandconsulting_2010/images/headers/*.{jpg,gif,png}';
$images = glob($httpdir, GLOB_BRACE);
```

Neither seems to find any images.  :s
FWIW, I can navigate to the directory explicitly and see the contents, like
[this](http://www.overlandconsulting.dreamhosters.com/wp-content/themes/overlandconsulting_2010/images/headers/)

It seems like the server won't let me access the images, but honestly I have no idea.

Thanks for any help!
jml

Comment: Turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. The `SERVER_NAME` path version is not going to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the url in the code has `wp_content` with an underscore while the link to the directory has `wp-content` with a hyphen.