# Load Random Image From Directory on Page Load (Without a List of File Names)

Tags: php, html, css

I have created a file in the root directory named "images.php" and that file can successfully pick and display an image at random from the directory "images/". My issue now is getting said image to display on my html webpage.

Here is the code for Images.php:

```
<?php
   $imagesDir = 'images/';
   $images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
   $randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];
   echo "<img src='$randomImage'>";
?>
```

How do I reference the chosen photo and display it in the HTML document?

Thank you for your guidance!

-Tony

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761252/how-to-get-random-image-from-directory-using-php

Comment: Those code snippets are different languages.. The first one is php and the second one is javascript. While it would be possible to use these together, it will be unnecessarily complicated! The answer linked by @Niels is much simpler

Comment: I thought they were different languages but the JavaScript was never clarified on the original post haha (again, in way over my head here). I found this line of code with the most votes but I'm having issues implementing it:
    $imagesDir = 'images/tips/';
    $images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
    $randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];

What do I need to put before or after that code other than the "<?php" and "?>" to properly execute the PHP tag? (If it helps, the full directory is just "images/").

Thank you again for your help!!!

Comment: @Tony why didn't you comment under the answer given? they can't read minds and have no idea if it worked for you or not.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner ....I thought I did? My comment is right above yours (or that's how it's showing on my screen.) My apologies for using the site incorrectly.

Comment: I'm closer to the answer but still lost on the final execution. I found this code that will pick an image from random in my "images/" directory and it displays the image when I navigate to mysite.com/images.php. I am now struggling to take that result and post it into my HTML home page.

Here is the code in images.php:

    <?php
       $imagesDir = 'images/';
       $images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
       $randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];
       echo "<img src='$randomImage'>";
    ?>

Do you have any more guidance? Thanks for your help!

Comment: under this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48359879/ not in comments here.

Comment: And please don't post code in comments since it loses its formatting making it unreadable. Instead, post any new code to the bottom of your original question by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: My bad! I've updated everything below!

Comment: Hey @funkFortyNiner, hovercraftfullofEels said that I shouldn't post under answers so I have updated my original question as per their request! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

this function choose random file or folder in path:

```
<?php
function randomFile($path) {
    $items = scandir($path);
    return $items[rand(2,count($items))];
}
?>
```

Comment: When I tired using your code in my HTML document or a stand alone PHP document nothing happened. I'm sure I did something wrong but like I said I'm not a coding expert and I apologize! I have updated the code in my question with something that gets me close except I cannot get the retrieved image to show on my html document.

Comment: hi! use above function like this : $filename = randomeFile('../images'); in filename variable is the name of random image and per request or per call this function return to you different filename.